Shutdown and Restart Issue on Dell Optiplex 7040: Need Help!
I'm experiencing a strange problem with my Dell Optiplex 7040. The startup goes smoothly, but things get complicated when I try to shut it down.
When I turn off the computer, it doesn’t completely shut down. The light stays on in orange, indicating that the system is still powered. This issue persists even during a restart, such as after a software update. The computer doesn’t actually turn off, and the orange light remains lit.
Initially, I thought it might be a Linux kernel issue. I was using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with kernel 6.8. I’ve tried versions 6.5.11, 6.4, and 6.11, but nothing has worked. The problem continues regardless of the kernel version.
To try to resolve this issue, I also updated the BIOS of my Optiplex 7040. Unfortunately, this hasn’t changed the situation.
I’m feeling a bit lost with this behavior. If anyone has encountered this kind of problem with an Optiplex 7040 or has any suggestions for resolving it, I would greatly appreciate any help!
Thank you in advance for your assistance. Feel free to ask if you need anything else!

You say when you turn off your computer. Are you using the power switch for this or a proper shutdown?

On Ubuntu GUI, to turn off or restart my computer, the only way is to keep pressing the shutdown button for 10 seconds, but the PC cannot restart via GUI or otherwise, it doesn't work not. it's not because of a hardware problem because I had Windows 10 before and everything worked. I read on another forum that it was surely the kernel kernel that optiplex does not support but that's not it unfortunately

Every time you use the power switch to shut down you may damage the OS.

how can I solve this problem? Should I upgrade to version 22 to see if the problem persists?
